# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'SelectedCityName'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am populating DropDownList in View and getting this error on POST.

Error:
    There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'SelectedCityName'.

Controller:

```
 public ViewResult Register()
    {
        var Cities = ILocaRepo.Cities.ToList(); 
        var Wards = ILocaRepo.Wards.ToList() ;
        var model = new RegisterViewModel
        {
            City = Cities.Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.CityID.ToString(),
                Text = x.CityName
            }),
            Ward = Wards.Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.WardID.ToString(),
                Text = x.WardName
            })
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            // Attempt to register the user
            try
            {
                MembershipService.CreateUser(model.User.Username, model.User.Password, model.User.Name, model.SelectedCityName, model.SelectedWardName, model.User.Address, model.User.Phone, model.User.Email, "Member");
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.User.Username, false);
                return RedirectToAction("ListProduct", "Product");
            }
            catch (ArgumentException ae)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ae.Message);
            }
        }


            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);

    }
```

View :

```
 <tr>
                <td class="info_label">City</td>
                <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.SelectedCityName,Model.City,"-- Chọn thành phố --",new { @class = "dropdown" })</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td class="info_label">Ward</td>
                <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedWardName, Model.Ward, "-- Chọn quận --", new { @class = "dropdown" })</td>
            </tr>
```

And the ViewModel:

```
 public User User { get; set; }
    public string SelectedCityName { get; set; }
    public string SelectedWardName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> City { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Ward { get; set; }
```

How can i get SelectedCityName to pass as parameter of RegisterUser method?. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your POST action you are rendering the same view in case of error (`return View(model);`). But you forgot to assign the `City` and `Ward` properties, the same way you did in your GET action and they will be null when this view is rendered.

So:

```
// If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form

// and don't forget to rebind City and Ward
model.City = ILocaRepo.Cities.ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem
{
    Value = x.CityID.ToString(),
    Text = x.CityName,
});
model.Ward = ILocaRepo.Wards.ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem
{
    Value = x.WardID.ToString(),
    Text = x.WardName,
});

// Now we can safely redisplay the same view
return View(model);
```

The reason why those 2 properties are null inside your POST action is pretty simple and lies into the design of HTML forms. In HTML when you submit a form containing a `<select>` element (which is what those `Html.DropDownListFor` helpers are generating), only the selected value is sent to the server. The list of available values is not sent to the server simply because it is assumed that you already have it somewhere on the server (because you rendered this form in the first place). So it is your responsibility, if you decide to redisplay the form in your POST action, to re-populate those collections in order to be able to display the dropdown lists properly.

Comment: Your meaning is repopulate the sourcer of the Dropdownlist and return another View?

Comment: No, you can return the same view if you wish. What you need to do is set the City and Ward properties as shown in my answer.

Comment: I just want to return the same View to display Validation Message, but why when i fill the valid value for each field, it always return to `// If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form`. The parameters i pass in the Register method is wrong? `model.SelectedCityName, model.SelectedWardName`.  Any help?

Comment: Is it because `model.SelectedCityName` and `model.SelectedWardName` are null inside your POST action or because some exception is thrown by your DAL?

Comment: What does the `m=>m.SelectedCityName` mean? It is the value or the name of ddl?

Comment: Actually it's used for both. The helper is using the lambda expression to deduce the name of the generated `<select>` field and is also using the corresponding property value on your view model to preselect the option.